# Adding new key-value pairs to JSON files using Python

Tags: python, json

I have a set of JSON files that contains some information.The below data is value for key 'BrowserInfo'.I want to extract the following information 
`Title` , `Links`, `Browser`,`Platform`,`CPUs` from what is given below, add the above fields as keys in the JSON file and extract their values and assign to those keys.

Title: Worlds best websit | mywebsite.com
Links: 225
Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 Ubuntu Chromium/41.0.2272.76 Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36
Platform: Linux x86_64
CPUs: 8

I have writtten a python program to descent into the directory and extract 'BrowserInfo' value from the JSON files.

```
# Set the directory you want to start from
rootDir = '/home/space'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
    for fname in fileList:
        fname='space/'+fname
        with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
            json_data = json.load(f)
            BrowserInfo = json_data['BrowserInfo']
            print(BrowserInfo)
```

How do I extract the values and add new key-value pairs to JSON files using Python.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have?

Comment: @KSFT - I want to extract induvidual information from the `BrowserInfo` and add them as new key value pairs to the JSON files.

Comment: What's wrong with something like `json_data[BrowserInfo.key]=BrowserInfo.value`?

Comment: @KSFT - I suspect you misunderstood the question.The entiere blob of data given above is the `value` for the `key` BrowserInfo. They are not in JSON format. They need to be parsed I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming, (*and this seems like a big assumption*), that `BrowserInfo` contains newline-separated key, value pairs, separated by `': '`, you could extract the keys / values with:

```
for line in BrowserInfo.splitlines():
    k,v = line.split(': ', 1)
```

Then just insert them wherever you want in the dictionary, e.g.:

```
json_data['BrowserInfo'] = {}
for line in BrowserInfo.splitlines():
    k,v = line.split(': ', 1)
    json_data['BrowserInfo'][k] = v
```

Comment: I read the file using json.load() will assigning json_data[] write it back to the file?

Comment: @liv2hak No, unfortunately you'd have to re-write the object to file with something like `json.dump`.

Comment: when I use split lines how do I discard a single line? for example the first line?

Comment: @liv2hak you could add a test like `if len(line) < 3: continue` as the first line inside your for loop -- 3 seems reasonable.

Comment: Instaed of line break ("\n") can I specify <br>. HTML break.

Comment: You can try, it'd depend on what was actually being used -- to do that you'd try `for line in BrowserInfo.split('<br>'):`

Comment: That worked.Now I have "Images: 17" in a line. k,v = line.split(':') on that line is giving `ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack` error

Comment: @liv2hak Make sure you provide the second parameter, `maxsplit = 1` or just `1`.

Comment: If I use k,v = line.split(':',1) it says  ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

Comment: @liv2hak that means the line you're trying to parse doesn't have a colon.

Comment: I figured.and have updated my logic.I have added a new question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326135/encoding-while-extracting-data-from-json-file

Answer (score 0):

A quick demo for the parsing

```
>>>import re, itertools

>>> BrowserInfo
'Title: Worlds best websit | mywebsite.com\nLinks: 225\nBrowser: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 Ubuntu Chromium/41.0.2272.76 Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36\nPlatform: Linux x86_64\nCPUs: 8'

>>> re.split(':|\n', BrowserInfo)
['Title', ' Worlds best websit | mywebsite.com', 'Links', ' 225', 'Browser', ' Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 Ubuntu Chromium/41.0.2272.76 Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36', 'Platform', ' Linux x86_64', 'CPUs', ' 8']

>>> s = re.split(':|\n', BrowserInfo)
>>> {pair[0].strip():pair[1].strip() for pair in itertools.izip(s[::2], s[1::2])}
{'Platform': 'Linux x86_64', 'Browser': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 Ubuntu Chromium/41.0.2272.76 Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36', 'CPUs': '8', 'Links': '225', 'Title': 'Worlds best websit | mywebsite.com'}
```

Thus

```
json_data['BrowserInfo'] = {pair[0].strip():pair[1].strip() for pair in itertools.izip(s[::2], s[1::2])}
```

would be your json