# encoding while Extracting data from JSON file

Tags: python, json

I have a simple python script as shown below.

```
with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
        json_data = json.load(f)
        message = json_data['Info']
        for line in message.split('<br>'):
                if(len(line) < 25):
                        print(line)
                        if ':' in line:
                                k,v = line.strip().split(':')
                                print(k,v)
```

I get k,v in the following format

```
(u'Images', u' 23')
(u'Links', u' 225')
```

The `message` output looks as below.

```
Title: Worlds best websit | mywebsite.com
Links: 225
Images: 23
Browser: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 Ubuntu Chromium/41.0.2272.76 Chrome/41.0.2272.76 Safari/537.36
CPUs: 8
```

I want to extract the data `Images:23` and `Links:225` and update that to the same json file `f` in the script.

If I were to do

```
json_data[k] = v
json.dump(json_data,f)
```

it corrupts the JSON file.Meaning If I add the above two lines to my code.
and do

```
cat output.json | python -m json.tool
```

from the command line.I get the following error.

`Extra data: line 2 column 1 - line 2 column 45376 (char 2139 - 47514)`

I don't understanding what is 'u' in the output? Is it some kind of encoding? If yes how do I process it?

Comment: u'' notates unicode string object in Python 2.

Comment: I see. How do I extract the data and add that back to the file?

Comment: What do you mean "it corrupts the json"?  Are you closing and re-opening the file between when you call `load` and `dump`?

Comment: I don't see those two lines in your code sample, when are they executed?

Comment: Not very "smart" solution is just replace whole the line with new line: Links: 225 => Links: 233542

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
import sys
import json
import re

fname = sys.argv[1]

openedFile = open(fname, 'r')
content = openedFile.read()
openedFile.close()

pattern = "Links: (\d+?)\nImages: (\d+?)"

matchObj = re.search(pattern, content)
if matchObj:
    openedFile = open(fname, 'w')
    newContent = {'Links': matchObj.group(1), 'Images': matchObj.group(2)}
    json.dump(newContent, openedFile)
    openedFile.close()
```

Comment: doesn't  json_dump() imply writing to the file as well?

Comment: Yes, json_dump() allows to write to the file. If the json file is open in r+ mode it allows you to read as well as write in the file

Comment: Then why are you suggestion the file be opened in 'r' mode?

Comment: Can you include your json file as well?

Comment: I am sorry I can't do that.